# Store multiple values + name in one object

Tags: c#

I want to draw multiple circles - that don't overlap each over - randomly. For that I want to make an **object that stores the circles radius and x and y position** (those are random). Then I want to **add these objects to an array** to later calculate if a circle overlaps with any other circle.

I know that in p5.js Javascript the code looks something like the following:

```
var circles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  var circle = {
    x: random(width),
    y: random(height),
    r: 32
  };
  circles.push(circle);
}

//and now I can draw the circles like following but in a loop:

ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r*2, circles[i].r*2);
```

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: you can use [Ellipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx) or write your own class.

Comment: Yes there are ways to do it in C# :)

Comment: On a VS form project the toolbox has a Visual Basic Power Packs with an Oval shape that can be used.  The oval has a size width and a size height that can be made equal to give a circle.  So you can have a List<Oval> circles = new List<Oval>();

Comment: This feels like a prank question... are you pranking us Benito?

Comment: @barakcaf No, I'm not pranking you. I'm just new to C# :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
public class Circle
    {
        // In C# this is called a "property" - you can get or set its values
        public double x { get; set; }

        public double y { get; set; }

        public double r { get; set; }
    }

    private static List<Circle> InitializeList()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        List<Circle> listOfCircles = new List<Circle>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            // This is a special syntax that allows you to create an object
            // and initialize it at the same time
            // You could also create a custom constructor in Circle to achieve this
            Circle newCircle = new Circle()
            {
                x = random.NextDouble(),
                y = random.NextDouble(),
                r = random.NextDouble()
            };

            listOfCircles.Add(newCircle);
        }

        return listOfCircles;
    }
```

The logic to actually draw this on the screen will depend on whether you're doing Windows Forms, ASP.NET, WPF, or whatever, but you'd do something like:

```
 foreach (Circle circle in InitializeList())
 {
     // This'll vary depending on what your UI is
     DrawCircleOnScreen(circle);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Circle {
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
}

class Vector2 {
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Read up on C# classes.